# List sending to another website and remember the link

Tags: html-lists

Hello i have made a list in lets say Homepage website the idea is that when i choose an option  it will send me to page with name Pages.htm and i want to remember the choise of the li.

```
Homepage
option 1--------> go to Pages.htm and add in the iframe the link1
option 2--------> go to Pages.htm and add in the iframe the link2
option 3--------> go to Pages.htm and add in the iframe the link3
```

Here is the code at page Pages.htm :

```
<a href="http://www.altasoft.gr/hermes/index.html" target="myfra"><span class="description">Ερμής Proffesional<br /> <em>(Ολοκληρωμένο Πληροφοριακό Σύστημα Οργάνωσης Πολιτικού Γραφείου)</em></span></a></li>
        <li style="margin-left: 0px" class="level1 parent"><a href="http://www.koino.gr/" target="myfra"><span>Κοινόχρηστα</span></a></li>
        <li style="margin-left: 0px" class="level1 parent"><a href="http://www.shae.gr/" target="myfra"><span>Συνεχές Ηλεκτρονικό Αρχείο Εκπαίδευσης </span></a></li>
        <li style="margin-left: 0px" class="level1 parent"><a href="pages/PageTK.htm" target="myfra"><span>Ταχυδρομικοί Κώδικες Ελλάδας</span></a></li>
        <li style="margin-left: 0px" class="level1 parent"><a href="http://sms.altasoft.gr/panel/index.asp?lang=el&disp_function=user_login&id=5E8A0F4B-063B-4A7A-81FE-99579AF44BAA" target="myfra"><span>SMS Bulk Messenger Center </span></a></li>
        <li style="margin-left: 0px" class="level1 parent"><a href="http://www.altasoft.gr/Software/TAM.htm" target="myfra"><span>Ταμειακή και Εμπορικό
για Β' κατηγορίας βιβλία</span></a></li>
<li style="margin-left: 0px" class="level1 parent"><a href="http://www.altasoft.gr/Software/TAM.htm" target="myfra"><span>Οργάνωση παιδιατρικού ιατρείου</span></a></li>
```

My problem is that at my HomePage.htm i want the same links to lead to Pages.html and send at the iframe the correct link 
thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with javascript.

Sample code:

```
...css:
<style>
    ul li .selected{
        font-weight:bold;
    }
</style>
...html:
<ul>
    <li><a href="" onclick="active_li(this)">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="" onclick="active_li(this)">Page 1</a></li>
</ul>

...js:
function active_li(element){
    element.setAttribute("class", "className");
}
```

Basically, when you click an `a` tag, it will call a javascript function that will change the class of the li element. And when that happens it will apply the css style.

`this` refers to the clicked element.

**Update:**

Maybe you are referring to:

`<iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="iframe_a">domain.com</a>`

From: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_name.asp

Comment: Thx for fast response!! but i dont undestand how this will work.. i dont want any css style to change... i want from Homepage that has no iframe to go to Pages that has iframe and the link is a List but when i click at home page option 1 i want to go to Pages and send at the iframe the link of option 1

Comment: ok to explain a bit more i got the Homepage.htm that has the List with the websites i want to show with the iframe but it has no space for iframe so when they click the List options i want to load the Pages.htm that has the Iframe and load the website they clicked at the Homepage.htm